# Ubuntu: How to get wireless lan and 10/100 running simultaneously?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, network-adapter

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 on a Dell Inspiron 6400.
I am able to get 10/100 Ethernet card and Wireless Lan working independently.

- Ethernet -> eth0
- Wireless Lan -> eth1.

If I restart/reboot my eth0 turns starts up fine.
If I then manually start my wireless connection (eth1), eth0 disappears.

There seems to be issues with wireless drivers:
I don't have the cleanest solution but I run this script:

```
rmmod b43 
rmmod b44 
rmmod ssb
rmmod wl
cp /home/stew/Desktop/brcmDriver/wl.ko  /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/kernel/net/wireless/
modprobe lib80211
insmod wl.
```

I then do:

```
wpa-supplicant (with essid and passphrase)
sudo ifup eth1
```

Is there any way I can have them running simultaneously?
From reading around I believe it's possible but not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Or any good references that will help me understand from a more fundamental level.

Comment: Did you try with network manager? Does network manager show you both interfaces?

Comment: Firstly apologies I didn't realize this had been moved to superuser (Thanks Gareth for doing that!). I uninstalled network manager as I read it can interfere with NIC bonding which is what my real goal is. But when it was running both interfaces worked (not sure if simultaneously or not.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would very suggest doing the following:

in:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

define the entry for your wired connection like so:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

or

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

You can do the same with Wireless connection as well but I think the Network Manager might work out better for you.

One question I do have to ask is:

Why 2 connections active at the same time?

Comment: Hi Karlson, I only just saw this! Thank you. I was experimenting with torrent and thought it might be able to take advantage of two different networks, also to provide redundancy and potentially incrementally increase bandwidth.

Comment: @user929821 The potential bandwidth that you can use only depends on your outbound connection and it's utilization

Comment: Two different networks...4G and cable. Although my example show wlan and lan....the eventual target was cable and cell. @Karlson not sure if the at id is working.

Comment: @user929821 at id?